# Cassandra Spark read performance - issue with double values

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a column family with all **string** columns of 5M rows (133GB).

My Spark program to read data from this keyspace, and print count, finishes in 80 sec.

But if I replace one string column with a **double** column, the same Spark program takes more than 300 sec.

I am trying to understand why is this happening. 
Is it because of any parsing happening back stage ?